# Toggling rows in and out in CSS Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have the following layout with 2 headers and 3 footers:

```css
.my-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header1"
        "header2"
        "mainAreaExpandMePlease"
        "footer1"
        "footer2"
        "footer3"
        ;
    grid-template-rows: 27px 27px 1fr 28px 28px 28px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The main area will expand to fill the gap left after showing the headers and footers.

I want to be able to toggle footers on and off (show / hide them) such that they collapse. With the code above, a gap will be left in place of the footer when we hide it.

How should I go about:

- Having a main area that always expands
- Having optional headers and footers which collapse, when hidden

Examples:

- If `header1` collapses, then `header2` should take its place and `mainAreaExpandMePlease` should expand to where `header2` used to be
- If `header2` collapses, then `mainAreaExpandMePlease` should expand up by another 27px
- If `footer3` collapses, then `footer2` takes place of `footer3`, `footer1` takes the place of `footer2` and `mainAreaExpandMePlease` will stretch down another 28px

Thank you!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jg6ho4wu/1/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header1"
        "header2"
        "mainAreaExpandMePlease"
        "footer1"
        "footer2"
        "footer3";
    grid-template-rows: 27px 27px 1fr 28px 28px 28px;
    height: 100%;
}

.header1 {
  grid-area: header1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header2 {
  grid-area: header2;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.mainAreaExpandMePlease {
  grid-area: mainAreaExpandMePlease;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.footer1 {
  grid-area: footer1;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer2 {
  grid-area: footer2;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer3 {
  grid-area: footer3;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="header1"></div>
  <div class="header2"></div>
  <div class="mainAreaExpandMePlease"></div>
  <div class="footer1"></div>
  <div class="footer2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="footer3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the height of the header and footer rows at the container level.

Set their heights on the items, and set their container heights to `auto`.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:  "header1" 
                        "header2"
                        "mainAreaExpandMePlease"
                        "footer1"
                        "footer2"
                        "footer3";
}

.header1 {
  height: 27px;
  grid-area: header1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header2 {
  height: 27px;
  grid-area: header2;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.mainAreaExpandMePlease {
  grid-area: mainAreaExpandMePlease;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.footer1 {
  height: 28px;
  grid-area: footer1;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer2 {
  height: 28px;
  grid-area: footer2;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer3 {
  height: 28px;
  grid-area: footer3;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="header1"></div>
  <div class="header2"></div>
  <div class="mainAreaExpandMePlease"></div>
  <div class="footer1"></div>
  <div class="footer2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="footer3"></div>
</div>
```